# #Ref! named ranges only showing after reopening workbook

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

After running my whole project, I attempt to delete all the named ranges in the base workbook with `#REF!` errors in them. I do this by running a `CleanUp` `Sub` at the end:

```
Sub CleanUp()
    Dim namy as name
    For Each namy In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        If InStr(1, namy.RefersTo, "#REF!") Then
            namy.Delete
        End If
    next namy
End Sub
```

However, my `CleanUp()` `Sub` doesn't detect my #REF! named ranges. I think it's a similar problem than in  [Delete Broken Named Ranges in Excel Using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40984119/delete-broken-named-ranges-in-excel-using-vba) (I know this is probably a duplicate, but I the question is unanswered and I don't have enough reputation to comment on the existing question and below I bring in some extra insights).

An interesting observation is that when I close and re-open my workbook, then the above Sub DOES identify the `#REF!` ranges. Can anyone explain this behaviour? If we can explain this, I suspect both this and the linked problem could be solved.

Comment: Have you tried putting a Calculate in to refresh the workbook and see if that makes a difference? After Dim namy as name

Comment: Would you like to delete `#REF` in active worksheet and make the cells empty ?

Comment: @QHarr that doesn't solve the problem. Another observation is that I can see the named ranges in the Name Manager, but it is not identified in the ActiveWorkbook.Names collection.

Comment: @Deepak I am trying to delete all #REF! named ranges from the Active Workbook's list of named ranges

Comment: Set your workbook calculation to Automatic and it should work. The code is working perfectly fine on my system..

Comment: I've reverted to avoid my project creating the #REF! named ranges in the first place so I don't need this `CleanUp` `Sub` in the end of my code.